# unexpected output in c (pointers)

Tags: c, output

Could someone point out the error in this

```
#include <stdio.h>
void modify (char*s,int x,int y)
{
    s[x]=s[y];
}
main()
{
   char* s = "random";
   modify(s,1,2);
}
```

The program ends abruptly. I know this may be a very easy question but i am new to c.
Thanks !

Comment: if i type 
'printf("\n%c",s[x]);'
the program works fine

Comment: what do expect? a program ends, when it's done with the code. what you have posted there is a program that does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because it crashes during the assignment in `modify`. The reason for that is that the pointer points to a constant string, one that can not be modified.

If you want to modify the string, you can declare it as an array instead:

```
char s[] = "random";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it. I once had the same problem. You should replace this line:

```
 char *s = "random";
```

With the following one:

```
char s[] = "random";
```